# Can someone explain this Binary tree code to me

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, nodes

[image]

I only understand the first step.  Where it says that *tmp = the node containing the data (7).

Comment: There are loads of tutorials about binary search trees on the internet.  Maybe you need to understand pointers first.

Comment: Possibly better to understand the first step as "tmp **points to** the node containing the data (7)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you diagram out each step, it should be easy to see what is happening:

1. `Node *tmp = root->right->left;`

[image: step 1]

2. `root->right->left = tmp->right;`

[image: step 2]

3. `tmp->right = root->right;`

[image: step 3]

4. `root->right = tmp->left;`

[image: step 4]

5. `tmp->left = root;`

[image: step 5]

6. `root = tmp;`

[image: step 6]

Comment: Great! How did you draw the images?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch mspaint